# Rendered font height is changing itself depending on word length? (formatting Japanese words)

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have no idea why this is happening...

Essentially, the font "size" (really, just the height it takes) is changing depending on the length of a word. I was unable to replicate this in English but it seems to happen consistently in Japanese. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

I don't think I have any relevant code that would be causing this.

The CSS for the header itself is very normal (was originally using `em` instead of `px` and got the same results):

```
.center-box-header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Is it some weird way Japanese fonts are made?

Answer (score 1):

Oh gosh, I just posted this and I realized the answer is so obvious haha...

It has nothing to do with the length, but rather the presence of kana. The longer words in the wordlist I'm using tend to have kana attached, which is why I thought the length was causing the increased height.

The most "correct" solution is probably to set the line-height or pick a different font. I'm personally going with a line-height.